# Checking claims with IAuthorizationFilter - "A suitable constructor for type could not be located"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, constructor, iauthorizationfilter

I am trying to check for Claims with an `IAuthorizationFilter` implementation. With following code it works just fine -

```cs
    public class ClaimsAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public ClaimsAttribute(string claimType, string claimValue) : base(typeof(ClaimsFilter))
        {
            this.Arguments = new object[] { new Claim(claimType, claimValue) };
        }
    }

    public class ClaimsFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly Claim _claim;

        public ClaimsFilter(Claim claim)
        {
            _claim = claim;
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var hasClaim = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.Any(p => p.Type == _claim.Type && p.Value == _claim.Value);
            if (!hasClaim)
            {
                context.Result = new ForbidResult();
            }
        }
    }

    public class DocumentController : Controller
    {
        [Claims(AppClaimTypes.Permission, "CanReadDocument")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetDocument()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

So I thought, I might check for multiple Claim values as well -

```cs
    public class Claims2Attribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public Claims2Attribute(string claimType, params string[] claimValues) : base(typeof(Claims2Filter))
        {
            this.Arguments = new object[claimValues.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < claimValues.Length; i++)
            {
                this.Arguments[i] = new Claim(claimType, claimValues[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Claims2Filter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly Claim[] _claims;

        public Claims2Filter(Claim[] claims)
        {
            _claims = claims;
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            bool hasClaim = false;
            foreach (var item in _claims)
            {
                hasClaim = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.Any(p => p.Type == item.Type && p.Value == item.Value);
                if (hasClaim)
                    break;
            }

            if (!hasClaim)
            {
                context.Result = new ForbidResult();
            }
        }
    }

    public class DocumentController : Controller
    {
        [Claims2(AppClaimTypes.Permission, "CanReadSecretDocument", "SecretAccess")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetSecretDocument()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

But now it throws error -

> InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type
>   'AuthorizationFilterTest.Claims2Filter' could not be located. Ensure
>   the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of
>   a public constructor.

I don't think its anything related to registering services, otherwise the first version wouldn't work. It seems something more trivial/silly, but I cannot find it.

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Its about **how** the arguments are passed to instantiate the target `IAuthorization` type (in this case `Claims2Filter`).

If the `Arguments` property (which is an array of object) contains multiple elements, then each element is considered a distinct argument to pass to a distinct parameter of the target `IAuthorization` type's constructor. In other words, a one-to-one mapping is required between the number of elements in `Argument` and the number of constructor parameter.

So, when the `Arguments` contains two Claim object, the runtime is actually expecting `Claims2Filter` to have the following constructor -

```cs
    public ClaimsFilter(Claim claim1, Claim claim2)
    {
            //
    }
```

To use a constructor (of the `IAuthorization` type) that accepts a single parameter which is an array of Claim object, the `Arguments` property (of the `TypeFilterAttribute` type) should contain a single element which is an array of Claim object.

So, the following change makes everything work as expected -

```cs
    public class Claims2Attribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public Claims2Attribute(string claimType, params string[] claimValues) : base(typeof(Claims2Filter))
        {
            var claims = new Claim[claimValues.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < claimValues.Length; i++)
            {
                claims[i] = new Claim(claimType, claimValues[i]);
            }

            this.Arguments = new object[] { claims };
        }
    }
```

I hope the explanation is clear enough.

Comment: This is really nice explanation, thank you.
Works perfect.